# Can we exec into container in a POD in K8S?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am putting docker image into POD.
We can exec into a Docker container using "docker exec..."
Similarly is there a way to exec into container in a POD to check some data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SSH to docker container in kubernetes cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485771/how-to-ssh-to-docker-container-in-kubernetes-cluster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of how to get inside the Kubernetes container in a Pod.

- [kubectl exec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/) ([reference link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec)) creates additional process in the Pod's namespace and connects your console to it's stdin/stdout.

Examples:

```
kubectl exec 123456-7890 date
kubectl exec 123456-7890 -c ruby-container date
kubectl exec 123456-7890 -c ruby-container -i -t -- bash -il
kubectl exec 123456-7890 -i -t -- ls -t /usr
```

- [kubectl attach](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/) ([reference link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#attach)) connects your console to stdin/stdout existing container process.

Example:

```
kubectl attach 123456-7890
kubectl attach 123456-7890 -c ruby-container
kubectl attach 123456-7890 -c ruby-container -i -t
kubectl attach rs/nginx
```

You can also connect to stdout/stderr of pod container(s) using [kubectl logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) command.

Examples:

```
kubectl logs nginx
kubectl logs nginx --all-containers=true
kubectl logs -lapp=nginx --all-containers=true
kubectl logs -p -c ruby web-1
kubectl logs -f -c ruby web-1
```

These answers on StackOverflow give you more information related to your question:

- [kubectl exec into contain of multi container pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979880/kubectl-exec-into-contain-of-multi-container-pod)
- [Execute bash command in pod with kubectl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247619/execute-bash-command-in-pod-with-kubectl/51247696)
- [Kubectl attach vs kubectl exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030252/kubectl-attach-vs-kubectl-exec)
- [How do you debug python code with kubernetes and skaffold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54874683/how-do-you-debug-python-code-with-kubernetes-and-skaffold)